# Are there well-known algorithms for fitting a polygon to an arbitrary shape?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, algorithm

I'm using the Chipmunk physics engine to make the levels for a 2D C game.  I'd like to be able to fit a polygon to an arbitrary shape to serve as the collision mask.  Given a black and white collision mask for an arbitrary level object like this:

[image: A black blob]

Are there any well-known algorithms for getting this:
[image: Now with a fitted polygon]

I could then use the red polygon to create a physics object to go with the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known as generating a concave hull, and is in the general case pretty complicated (much more so than the convex hull).

One commonly-recommended method is using [alpha shapes](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/belair/alpha.html).

There are more good resources on the problem [here](http://ubicomp.algoritmi.uminho.pt/local/concavehull.html), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83593/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-to-generate-a-2d-concave-hull).