# How to form a concave shape out of convex shapes?

Tags: mathematics, graphics, box2d, sfml

I'm trying to get around the rule of only being able to form convex shapes in the SFML C++ library.

> To do this I'm planning on testing given vertices, and if concave,
>   splitting the vertices into groups, testing each groups' concaveness,
>   and repeating until a full set of convex shapes results that look
>   just like the original shape when put together

What I would like to know is...

- **What the equation for testing a shapes concaveness is: what is it and how does it work?**
- **How would I split up the vertices of the concave shape so in the end the shape is formed out of as few convex shapes as possible?**
- **Whats the best practice for achieving my goal?**

Thanks!

Comment: User posted this same question to stackoverflow.  Answer is already there:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686279/how-to-form-a-non-concave-shape-out-of-concave-shapes

Comment: yeah should i leave this question here on gamedev since it pertains to that to (for futur users) or delete this?

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9680/polygon-triangulation-algorithm

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a top down approach, try a bottom up one.  I.e., grow convex regions out of sets of vertices (starting with a tetrahedron), then grow these by adding adjacent (in terms of triangle connectivity).  When you cannot find another vertex to add, find an unadded tetrahedron (easily started from 2 adjacent triangles with non-reflexive angle on the interior shared edge), and repeat.

Detecting if adding the vertex will maintain convexity is relatively easy (note that you are not just adding to a convex hull - effectively, if adding a vertex to the convex hull you are growing results in one of the surface vertices becoming interior to the hull, it is not a valid point to add).  The tricky bit is determining which vertices should be added to minimize the number of convex volumes.  In practice this is a hard optimization problem, and heuristics are likely good enough to get a "good enough" decomposition.

Incidentally, if you want to read up more on this, the term you want to search for is "3D Convex Decomposition".  FYI, a BSP tree will also give you a convex decomposition of a non-convex object, but it will be far from minimal.

Comment: Is htis faster than my other answer? or less memory-hogging?

Comment: Also could you look at the questions i posted as comments under the other answer?

Comment: The other approach is close to working, but the convex decomposition can be really bad and won't handle some cases. Consider two disjoint spheres: First, the capsule enclosing both spheres is found, then half of each sphere becomes its own object: so far so good, but then the next step will find two disjoint, possibly coplanar sets (failure case, since no volume is found). Bottom up approach: the region will grow to one sphere, then stop when it cannot grow to the other sphere. Then it will grow a tetrahedron from the other sphere, and finish correctly, with an optimal subdivision.